# designing GameController UI relation

Tags: c#, design-patterns, unity-game-engine, unity3d-2dtools

So this is my first time creating a more complex game using Unity. I'm working on an TBS (Turn Based Strategy) game and would like some advice.

Currently I have a persistent UI object that houses all of my UI assets/scripts/etc that moves from scene to scene. I also have a GameController script that manages my game state within my game scene.

What I am trying to do is to have additional UI elements pop up when I select or deselect units of specific types.

I would like to know what recommended best practices or known design patterns are for dealing with this situation. (Preferably Unity specifically)

- Should I use some of the built in Unity functions to find my UI from
  my GameController and influence it that way?
- Should I design some better 'god object' that manages the interaction
  between these two?
- Should I do something else?

Some simple illustration or description of design would be more than enough to help me out. I'm just stuck trying to figure out what the right approach is here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Easiest way possible in my opinion is:

1. Create "selection UI"
2. Link it with public variable to select/deselect script
3. Make initialization method for UI that will change what that UI shows depends on selected unit

But I think there isn't the best way, it really depends how you designed whole game. You can also create script for UI with singleton pattern and then use it where you want to. I'd like to keep everything as simple as possible.

Comment: Thanks, this is actually what I ended up doing. Still not convinced this is the best approach but I will accept this as the answer.